# Can we think of a non-symmetric product type in Haskell?

Tags: type-theory, functional-programming, category-theory, haskell

**Meta note: I asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63178743/can-we-think-of-non-symmetric-product-data-types-in-haskell) a while ago. It got an answer:**

> **`type a /\!! b = (a, ((b -> Void) -> Void))`**

**Unfortunately, I do not reckon it to be quite right: `() /\!! a ≅ a` does not hold.**

**I do not want to delete the question on Stack Overflow as the answerer still put quite some effort in (and I did not manage to migrate it here). I will close it as a duplicate, if I get the fitting answer here, if that's alright. We discussed this issue [on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354404/moving-a-two-month-old-post-across-sites-denied#comment1184357_354411).**

---

[`Control.Category.Constrained.Cartesian`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html#t:Cartesian) is a class for monoidal categories with some natural transformations (the product is `(,)` and the unit defaults to `()`; the product cannot be changed, unlike the sum in [`Control.Category.Constrained.CoCartesian`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html#t:CoCartesian)).

- `regroup` and `regroup'` are for `(a, (b, c)) ≅ ((a, b), c)`;
- `attachUnit` and `detachUnit` are for `a ≅ (a, unit)`.

They *almost* give us the monoid. The only thing that is left is `(unit, a) ≅ a`. Here we use `(,)` being symmetrical: `(a, b) ≅ (b, a)`.

As far as I know, it is not a general property. Bartosz Milewski attributes the property to symmetrical monoidal categories (for example, [here](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2017/05/13/enriched-categories/)).

Is there some product type in Haskell which is not symmetrical?

Comment: The *product* of types is necessarily symmetric, because you can always swap with `(b, a)`, as you mention. However, there are many tensor products of types that are nonsymmetric: take any associative non-commutative binary type operator. If this type operator has a unit, then it will form a nonsymmetric monoidal category.

Comment: @varkor what is a **tensor product** and how is it different from simply **product**? Can you give an example of a **non-symmetric tensor product**, please?

Comment: A (cartesian) product is a particular kind of tensor product that has projections $A \otimes B \to A$ and $A \otimes B \to B$, which satisfy a [universal property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory))). I realised that I don't think Haskell is able to express the examples of noncommutative type operators (without, say, type-level lambdas), so I don't have an answer to your question. I just wanted to clarify the terminology.

Comment: @varkor I suppose we can use the `A ⊗ B -> A` and `A ⊗ B -> B` arrows to get `A ⊗ B -> (B, A)`. But is it generally true that we have an arrow back (using the properties you wrote about)? Is it true for such products in Haskell?

Comment: It's not true in general, but in Haskell, we're limited in the type constructors we can actually form: we can take combinations of the (cartesian) product and the coproduct, but as far as I see, these are going to be either symmetric or non-unital (see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155939/what-other-monoidal-structures-exist-on-the-category-of-sets), for instance). The `->` type constructor has similar issues. Declaring new type constructors with `data` isn't good enough, because you can't express equations on them. I get the feeling it may not be possible to find one.

Comment: @varkor thank you for your help! You mentioned type-level lambdas. Can you please show how they help us in coming up with such a product?

Comment: For example, if we can write arbitrary functions at the type level, then we can declare a type operator $\lambda (A, B) . \mathsf{if}\ A = \mathsf{Void}\ \mathsf{then}\ B\ \mathsf{else}\ A$, i.e. a type operator that is always equal to the left operand, unless the left operand is the empty type. This has the empty type for a unit, and is associative, but is clearly not symmetric.

Comment: @varkor, why wouldn't just an ability to compare types do? That is if we can find out whether the type is empty, `A ⊗ B = if A == Void then B else A` seems fine to me without lambdas. Besides, you can make this into an answer, if you want - I will definitely **+1**. If you do, it would make sense to add a bit more detail on Haskell - what leads us into thinking that Haskell products are either symmetrical or non-unital?

Comment: If that syntax worked, then that would be enough, yes. But it was my impression it wasn't possible to define types like that in Haskell (even without the `if-then-else`). I don't think I quite have a complete answer to your question yet, though perhaps one could develop one: the basic idea is that there are only so many ways to declare types in Haskell, so if all of these are either symmetric or non-unital, then their composites must be too. I think this might be enough, but to have a definitive answer, one needs to check all type forming operations exhaustively.